# Understanding service account vs scopes for gcloud compute instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-api-nodejs-client

I've created a gcloud compute instance where I would like to perform operations within the same project using the `storage.objects.get` and `firebasedatabase.instances.update` scopes.

Each instance is created with the Compute Engine default service account `numbers-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` which has `Editor` roles within the project. Because of this I assumed the instance would have the required permissions when initialized using

```js
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});
```

Requesting a firestore instance however results in the error `Request had insufficient authentication scopes`.

Now I've noticed that if I `gcloud compute instances describe my-instance` the result mentions both an email and scopes for serviceAccounts:

```json
"serviceAccounts": [
    {
      "email": "numbers-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

What's the relation between the service account email and the predefined scopes? Is the instance not applying all scopes of the service account?

Even if I want to adjust my scopes I would need some help on translating the `storage.objects.get` and `firebasedatabase.instances.update` iam definitions to the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/scope` format. (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebasedatabase.instances.update` does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

Roles such as Owner, Editor and Viewer are what we call primitive roles [1], They don't contain the permissions for every resource in GCP. I would suggest creating a custom role with the desired permissions or selecting the appropriate predefined role [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_roles

[2] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#firebase-roles